# Синхронизация по объекту

Tags: многопоточность, java

В нити1 происходит synchronized по объекту. Нить2 тоже доходит до блока synchronized по тому же объекту в тот момент, когда нить1 не вышла из synchronized. Вопрос такой: нить2 будет ждать, пока нить1 не отпустит synchronized или как? И что будет при большом кол-во таких нитей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. Встанут в очередь и будут ждать пока объект не освободится

Answer (score 2):

Да, все верно - `synchronized` объект блокирует доступ к нему других нитей.

Вообще, для работы с нитями рекомендуется вкурить книжку/исходники [Doug Lea Java Concurrent Programming](http://g.oswego.edu/)